# Unity Rewarded Ads coding Rewards

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

How can i make it so after watching 2 rewarded ads all the levels in my game are unlocked and  playable.
Currently i have it so you have to complete the level in order to unlock that level and be able to play it at any given time.

public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)

```
{
    if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId) && showCompletionState.Equals(UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED))
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity Ads Rewarded Ad Completed");
        // Grant a reward.

        

        // Load another ad:
        Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question sounds familiar, do we know each other? In any case you need to add a bit more context to your question. What are you using for ads and what is your current code regarding level unlock.

Comment: I set the player prefs with my game manager when i complete the level the i lock and unclok it with this script :

Comment: public Button[] lvlButtons;

    void Start()
    {
        int levelAt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelAt", 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < lvlButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 2 > levelAt)
                lvlButtons[i].interactable = false;
        }
        
    }

Comment: Just set LevelAt to a last level index, so that it will unlock all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PlayerPrefs system to track the number of ads they've watched. Increment that PlayerPref each time they watch an ad.

Then change your level configuration code to check for that PlayerPref in addition to which levels they've completed.

Comment: how do i code that?

Comment: It look like you're already using PlayerPrefs to store data, so do the same thing for the ads they've watched. Then check that value in your conditional inside your for loop.

Comment: Could you guide me a but with the code?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that I already have. You've already used PlayerPrefs and already have a conditional for updating the level button.

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses PlayerPrefs to achieve level unlocking.

Level Structure:

[image]

Add a script where the level is confirmed to pass.

```
 public int jiesuo;
 jiesuo = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
 PlayerPrefs.SetInt("jiesuo", jiesuo);
```

Then add the level script to the level artboard.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class level : MonoBehaviour
{
    Button[] button;
    public GameObject panl;
    int jiesuo1;
    void Start()
   {
        jiesuo1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("jiesuo");
        button = new Button[panl.transform.childCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < panl.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        button[i] = panl.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < button.Length; i++)
    {
        button[i].interactable = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jiesuo1+1; i++)
    {
        button[i].interactable = true;
     }
 }
     void Update()
    {
    
    }
 }
```

button add:

[image]

```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

  public class levelbutton : MonoBehaviour
 {
      // Start is called before the first frame update
      void Start()
     {
    
      }

      public void OnStartGame(int SceneNumber)
      {
          SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneNumber);


       }
     void Update()
     {
    
     }
   }
```